# Star wars Commander:What is a fast way to upgrade defenses?

Tags: star-wars-commander

I have been playing star wars Commander for a few weeks now but it seems like I am making little progress any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get resources is to open daily crates , raid other players , do the missions , enter a squad war etc. If you complete a whole chapter in the missions you can receive a bunch of crystals. Grind for them and you can upgrade your base real fast.